what can we say about two anti-commute matrices?
In linear algebra, we know that if two matrices are both diagonalizable and if they commute then they can be simultaneously diagonalized.
What can we say if they are anti-commutable? This is relevant in quantum mechanics, as fermionic creation operators anti-commute.

You mean if $AB=-BA?$

If $AB = -BA$, then $AB^2 = -BAB = B^2 A$, so $A$ and $B^2$ can be simultaneously diagonalized, as can $A^2$ and $B$.
However, $A$ and $B$ might not be simultaneously diagonalizable.
For example, you might consider
$$ A = \pmatrix{  0 & 1\cr 1 & 0\cr},\ B = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & -1\cr}$$

showing that the squares form an ideal of diagonal matrices in a common basis. So, in an irreducible representation, one generates a Clifford algebra  corresponding to the squares as a metric. The 2-products  A B form a Lie sub-algebra , such that an the algebra, generated by an anticommuting basis, is direcetly connected to a symmetry group over the generators.
